# Difference between "magnitude" and "extent"

Tags: differences

Is there a difference between the two when used as in the following sentences?

```
The extent of the disaster was initially underestimated.
```

vs.

```
The magnitude of the disaster was initially underestimated.
```

Both seem very similar, but I haven't found either as a synonym for the other in a Thesaurus (only as related words).

Comment: They're at not synonyms. Magnitude is about the size, extent is about the spread in the context. Think 'severe but localized, versus 'mild but widespread.'

Comment: @Kris completely agree. extent:magnitude :: further:farther

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Longman Dictionary of Contemprary English* says, for *extent*,

> how large, important, or serious something is, especially something such as a problem or injury; *It is too early to assess the full extent of the damage.*

and for *magnitude*,

> the great size or importance of something; *They did not seem to appreciate the magnitude of the problem.* (and also) the brightness of a star; the force of an earthquake

So both *magniutde* and *extent* can apply to size and/or importance.

The difference is somewhere else: it lies in the adjective 'great' (Latin 'magnus'); with *extent*, the people estimated the size and/or importance of the disaster to be great or small – we do not know – but it was greater than they tought; with *magnitude*, the people estimated the size and/or importance to be great and it was **even greater** than they thought.

Earthquakes and stars, even if their magnitude is small, still involve incredibly large/great amounts of energy…